c++ How to design/declare "callbacks" that support a comparison operation - need to find and remove callbacks from list
I believe this is not a duplicate question. Other similar questions ask something like "how can I compare std::function objects for equivalence/equality?". The answer seems to be simply "one cannot". Instead, I am asking "how can I represent a function that includes captures and can be compared for equality?".
Taking a step back: I am defining a callback type, and "clients" will "register" with the callback "notifier". The notifier must be able to prevent duplicate callbacks from being registered, and allow for removal of specified callbacks. I started simply with:
typedef bool(*Callback)(const MyClass&);

As the design progressed, I realized I would need to support (also, but not only) member functions as callbacks, which I represented as lambdas:
auto myLambda = [this](const MyClass& myclass) {...};

Researching how to declare this type, I ran across several sites suggesting use of std::function. My typedef then became:
typedef std::function<bool(const myClass&)> Callback;

So I construct a std::vector to hold my Callbacks. Finding a Callback became a problem. I thought I had solved the problem with:
bool findCallback(const Callback& cb, const std::vector<Callback>& callback_v) {
    std::find_if(callback_v.begin(), callback_v.end(),[cb](Callback& other) {
        return *cb.target<bool(const MyClass&)>()==*other.target<bool(const MyClass&)>();
    }) != callback_v.end();
}

This does not work, as any comparison always results in a match. So the question is not "how to compare std::function<> objects", but rather "how can I represent callbacks including both static and member functions in such a way as to have a consistent signature as an element in a container (std::vector) and supporting comparison for equality?".

You'd need some sort of meta data to do this generically. Maybe once we get reflection...

A common technique is for the Register function to return some opaque handle, and for Unregister to take that handle as a parameter.  Internally, that handle could just be a sequentially assigned ID. So you don't compare callbacks, you compare handles - a much simpler problem.

from a design POV why would you want a lambda, something that's "anonymous", being recognized and held accountable for equality check? Like what @NathanOliver said you are better off with storing metadata, in a custom class that supports operator()

If I were to always capture some value (even an unused "dummy") so the std::function would never degenerate to a *func(), is there some way to access the address of the local class (a functor??) that is created, allowing for comparison that way?

Simple, migrate to Qt5.6 (last LGPL 2 allowing branch), and use signals/slots, meaning, consider connections as adding a callback and disconnect as remove.

Note that Windows has the CreateWindow function, but not MacOS or Linux, I mean, without Qt you would need to rewrite your entire app to support multi-platform.

I don't feel confident enough to answer this, but I think there is no way to semantically compare 2 generic functions without having some metadata describing them (unique ID at least). Consider e.g. that you declare to identical lambdas auto myLambda1 = [this](const MyClass& myclass) {...}; and auto myLambda2 .... Should they be considered equal? Or how about auto myLambda3 = [myLambda2](auto) { return myLambda2(); }.

@Top-Master if I understand your comment, that would be a big effort (and dependency) for a minor portion of the package's functionality. While I don't doubt it can be made to work, I'm looking for something I can do in my design to avoid this complexity I've created.

@pptaszni yes, there are many complex issues to consider when attempting to implement a robust comparison of std::function. It appears that is why there is no such comparison made available in std library. I am wondering if there is an alternative approach I can use to avoid use of std::function entirely. Perhaps address of function and offset (null for non-member functions) but I have only a vague idea of what that would be -- or if it would work.

An alternative to the suggestion by @Top-Master is to use CopperSpice's CS_Signal library (https://github.com/copperspice/cs_signal).
Copperspice is itself a fork of Qt from quite a ways back, but is fully open source.
You can use the library there for all sorts of connections and the ergonomics is similar to Qt. A C++17 compiler is required though.

For me, I generally either think very hard about it, and then find out that I don't care about "duplicates" and don't need to remove callbacks. And if I do need to remove them, I return a "handle" that follows the usual C++ scoping, so I can unregister the callback -- which, again, means I don't care about "duplicates". If I want to do the same thing twice, who am I to argue with me? Another easy way would be to give names to your callbacks, but that requires that these are unique throughout the application.

@ChristianStieber you make some good points. I am thinking very hard about duplicate prevention. It may not be necessary... but seems that it could be fragile, if use of the system goes beyond what I anticipate. I feel confident that removal is necessary; the "client" (listener) is not guaranteed to be valid for the lifetime of the program's execution. If destroyed, the callback would very likely be dealing with invalid or null pointers/data. Could you elaborate a bit more on your idea of "give(ing) names to (my) callbacks"?

@ags the "giving names" is trivial -- just adding an additional "name" parameter to the registration function. This does leave uniqueness to the users, though -- if everyone just uses "my callback" as name, instead of something more sensible, it's not going to work. On some occasion I use types instead of names (making the registration function a template) -- makes it easier to be unique as most users could just use the class they are working on, or make an empty class in their sourcefile to use as "name".
